# update facebook status with php/curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have a page on facebook and i want to be able to update my page when someone post a classifieds ad on my website.

currently the website in on my localhost [wamp] and am testing it from there

i have tried the solutions provided in the following websites but none of them seems to work

http://360percents.com/posts/php-curl-status-update-working-example/
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/03/01/php-curl-bot-to-update-facebook-status/

All am looking for is simple function to update my facebook page as such
Update_status(email,password,status);

Comment: Can you add some more detail/provide some code you've tried? Do you want to update the facebook page as the page or as the user using your site? Have you granted the correct permissions to your application? Check out http://developers.facebook.com and then post some specific examples of where you're struggling if possible

Comment: If you can, use the facebook php-sdk. It´s much easier than using curl

Answer (score 0):

1) You need a Facebook app.

2) You then need a long lived access token for your Facebook page.

3) Using that access token you can post to your page. [ You can have a cron job running that checks whether any user has posted any new content, if yes then use the access token to post to page ]